# Volume of region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of the region determined by:

First octant, $z+y=1$ and $z+x=1$.

My response is the result of the integrals:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{1-y} dzdydx+\int_0^1\int_0^x \int_0^{1-x}dzdydx$$

Is this correct? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. It should rather be
$$
   \int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^{1-\min(x,y)} \mathrm{d}z \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{d}x
$$
See the picture:

[image]

Comment: thanks. How do I get the $\min(x,y)$? Why my response is not correct?

Comment: @Hiperion Sorry my previous comment made no sense. The reason your result is not correct, is that you want to integrate over region where $0<x+z<1$ and $0<y+z<1$ *both* hold. The first integral integrates over a region, where $0<x+z<1$ may not hold.

Comment: Since you need both $x+z<1$ and $y+z<1$, it means that $z<1-x \land z<1-y$, that is $z < \max(1-x, 1-y) = 1- \min(x,y)$